# What's the meaning of 'trim' when use in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, trim

The link is http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-trim

I'm beginner in mongoosejs. I just don't get it...

I saw this question [How to update mongoose default string schema property trim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204611/how-to-update-mongoose-default-string-schema-property-trim) but don't understand why trim. Im creating my first schema today like a 'hello world'.

I saw this to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trim/info ... but when i need to use it, i want to learn more about it. Im looking for an explanation for a beginner...

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It's basically there to ensure the strings you save through the schema are properly trimmed. If you add `{ type: String, trim: true }` to a field in your schema, then trying to save strings like `"  hello"`, or `"hello "`, or `"  hello "`, would end up being saved as `"hello"` in Mongo - i.e. white spaces will be removed from both sides of the string.

Comment: @bruno.karklis Read documents about javascript trim function.

Comment: @xpto Why this behave like that as normal javascript function won't behave the same
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "     Hello World!     ";
  alert(str.trim());
}
</script> <!-- This will display "Hello World!"

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI because in that time i dint know the JS syntax well, i was learning, my background was SQL and PHP, and the thinking process is diferent, you dont use php syntax in SQL databade to do something. Besides that i knew that the database was made in JS, i was not aware that i could use JS syntax in the database.

Comment: another question is that "should we really handle such things at DB level?" since it can be handled through server code.  Are there any performance benefits?

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior

It you will add " hello world", its will be "hello world"

Answer (score 3):

Using trim will help in removing the white spaces present (beginning and ending of the string) in the string that you want to save to the DB like

```
"ABC " , "     ABC  ",
```

will be saved in the form

```
"ABC"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
trim: true
```

will remove leading and trailing whitespaces
so something like

> " hello "

will be saved as

> "hello"

Answer (score 0):

trim in Mongoose  removes the space if it is at the beginning or end of the string ,

exemple : ' hello world '

when you activate trim in attribute It is saved : 'hello world'

Answer (score -1):

trim in mongoose use to remove the white spaces from the strings

Comment: Trim removes whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, we use trim in mongoose to remove white space in a string.

**For example:**
without use trim or `trim:false`

```
"mong oose "
```

with use trim or `trim:true`

```
"mongoose"
```

**Note:** gain better experience to read mongoose doc.

Comment: As said in documentation: JavaScript strings have a trim() method that you can use to can use to remove leading and trailing whitespace from a string. Trim don't remove white space in the middle of words. so trimmed "mong oose " is "mong oose". Please check and fix